# What App permissions do I have before Facebook review?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, facebook

We're developing mobile app on both iOS and Android. In order to Facebook liking and sharing functional our apps will be asking for **publish_actions** permission from Facebook's Graph API. I'm in stuck - I haven't received such permission for regular user (neither developer, nor tester in Facebook's roles terms).

For example (in Swift) after user has logged following code was executed:

```
 for p in result.grantedPermissions {
   print(p as! NSString)
 }
```

And I saw:
*contact_email

user_friends

public_profile*
Actually question is: Is it normally if I didn't get granted publish_actions WITHOUT review request for regular user if I already set this permission in code?

Comment: _“if I already set this permission in code?”_ – all you do in your code is specify what permissions you _want to ask_ the user for on login. But normal users (that don’t have a role in the app) will not be asked for those permissions if they are not reviewed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may use this (**public_profile, user_friends** and **email**) permission without review from Facebook you can access the user details, if you are used the `non-optional` permissions for example **publish_actions** for sharing purpose you need to submit your app for review on Facebook before submit your app on apple.

for extended permissions for optional and non-optional see this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)